# XSLT pass node into CDATA JS

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<AAA>
  <BBB>Total</BBB>
</AAA>
```

Transforming it with the following xslt using the xsl:copy-of tag, because I want to use the xml to create a xml doc in js.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <![CDATA[
    function myFunc() {
      xmlStr = ']]><xsl:copy-of select="/"/><![CDATA[';
    }
  ]]>
</xsl:template>
```

The output looks like this

```
    function myFunc() {
      xmlStr = '<AAA>
  <BBB>Total</BBB>
</AAA>';
    }
```

JS doesn't like this because of the missing semicolons ending the lines.
How can I fix my xsl to get the below result:

```
function myFunc() {
  xmlStr = '<AAA><BBB>Total</BBB></AAA>';
}
```

I've tried normalize-space() and translate() but they strip the tags from the xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`xsl:strip-space` element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_preserve-space.asp):

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="AAA"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<![CDATA[
  function myFunc() {
    xmlStr = ']]><xsl:copy-of select="AAA"/><![CDATA[';
  }
]]>
</xsl:template>
```

It will remove all of the whitespace from the element `AAA` before copying it. You have to watch out, though, because it will remove any internal spacing from text nodes under `AAA` as well, so it's kind of overkill. If you have some elements where space needs to be preserved, list them as exceptions in an `xsl:preserve-space` element. But judging from your example I don't think that will be a concern.

Comment: @davomarti: Be sure that your XML can never contain any single quotes, or your JavaScript will break. Especially, make sure your XML does not contain user-generated data, since this approach carries a high XSS risk. Best is to request the XML separately from the server via AJAX, instead of directly injecting it into your JS code.

Comment: Thanks Welbog,
That's what I was looking for. 

Tomalak,
That makes alot of sense, but I'm working inside a framework and the best I can do is get the xml through xsl.